# Getting "Cannot create URL from path [] in Spring example

Tags: spring, spring-boot, command-line-interface

Getting   on sample exercise from "Spring Boot in Action" :

> Cannot create URL from path []  Invalid URI
>   [jar:file:D:\spring143\lib\spring-boot-cli-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/];

No related problem in book Errata or on this site..  Also ran w/latest Spring boot version Cli.  Need next steps to resolve this problem.

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The right command to start is not

> `spring run .`

(copied out of the book)
but

> `spring run *.*`

Comment: You should communicate this back as "errata" to Spring.